# How to get SmsManager object of selected SIM card using 'Java Reflection'?

Tags: android, reflection, sms-gateway

I'm using **reflection method for get smsManager object** of SIM card.

It working perfectly to get default smsManager object of **default SIM** by using "getDefault" method,

```
getContext().getClassLoader().loadClass("android.telephony.SmsManager").getMethod("getDefault", new Class[0]).invoke(null, new Object[0]);
```

But I **want to send messages from selected SIM card** (option given to select SIM card in my application).

I know, there is a method in SmsManager class to get smsManager object of selected SIM card using SIM subscriptionID **'getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(int subscriptionID)'** added in API level 22 (lollipop).

It works perfectly using below code,

**SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(subscriptionID);**

But I want to using by reflection method. So,when I'm using this method by reflection,

```
getContext().getClassLoader().loadClass("android.telephony.SmsManager").getMethod("getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId", Integer.class).invoke(null, subID);
```

It throws exception :  **'java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId [class java.lang.Integer]'**

Can anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: *Can anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong?* you are using method which doesn't exist

Comment: I want to use this method https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId%28int%29

Comment: then use it ... why you need reflection? if method doesn't exists on the device reflection will not spawn it automagically

Comment: @TejasPatel you want to skip sim selection dialog.

Comment: Are you running this on a device that has Android 5.1 or later? If not, this is not going to work, as Selvin already stated. If you are, then there's no need for reflection. Just put the call to `getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId` inside an `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 22) {}` and annotate the method with `@TargetApi(22)` if necessary.

Comment: @Michael `SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(SIMID);
                        sm.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumberToSend, null, parts,
                                sentIntents, deliveryIntents);`   When this code execute it show a sim selection dailog can i skip that dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integer is not int.

int.class instead of Integer.class

Comment: Thanks JesusS for make me correct. Now it's working.